# How do I put user input into a batch file on windows 7 ultimate x86?

Tags: file, batch-file, input

Here is my code so far:

```
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0
echo This is a batch file to convert Wii Iso Archive format to Wii Backup File System format using Wiimms wit/wwt programs provided they are installed on your pc you must edit this batch file to convert the game of your choice just edit the file paths and you'll be fine just keep the filenames the id6 tag of the game.
pause
wit copy D:/RHOP8P.wia D:/RHOP8P.wbfs -v -v -v -v
echo Conversion complete. Press any key to exit command prompt.
pause
```

What I want to do is make it so that the id6 tag "RHOP8P" is something the user inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SET command:

```
set /p _id6=Enter an id6 tag:
wit copy D:/%_id6%.wia D:/%_id6%.wbfs -v -v -v -v
```

Comment: thank you Tony this did the trick Stephan's answer was the same just with echo test: which wasn't needed but I did use it for a message

Answer (score 1):

```
set /p var="input please: "
echo Test: %var%
copy D:\%var%.wia D:\%via%.wbfs -v -v -v -v
```